# % sign randomly appears in every output of terminal in vs code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

Everytime I use the terminal to print out a string or any kind of character, it automatically prints an "%" at the end of each line. This happens everytime I try to print something from C, havent . I think it might be something with vscode, and have no idea how it came or how to fix it.I just want my output to be clear.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
cd "/Users/abishekdhakal/Chapter 1/" && gcc 01_practice.c -o 01_practice && "/Users/abishekdhakal/Chapter 1/"01_practice
abishekdhakal@MacBook-Air Chapter 1 % cd "/Users/abishekdhakal/Chapter 1/" && gcc 01_practice.c -o 01_practice && "/Users/abishekdh
akal/Chapter 1/"01_practice
Hello World%
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If ```%``` is your prompt, then in your ```printf``` line, you need to include a ```\n```.

Comment: Thank u so much.Now I get clear output.

Comment: I don't see any relevance to VS Code, btw, it seems you're using GCC's C compiler. In any case, as a new user here, read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Answer (score 0):

printf doesn't include the linefeed, so once run, the command prompt is shown right afterwards.

Just include `\n` at the end of the string.

i.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```